# How can I put my Android application listening for server information?

Tags: android, android-studio, server

I'm making a parking assistance project. It consists in Arduino receiving information from sensors, then send it to Raspberry Pi and then send the info to Android to be displayed. I'm new to Android and I cannot find how to be listening for the server info. Also, I want to be connected by Wi-Fi to receive the information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a database and put your readings from sensor there. Then your android app can read the values. Firebase real time database can be a good choice which is very compatible with Android and easy to use.
Some other choices you may have is to send value via email if you just want to notify your android of an event and if you are using raspberry Pi as well.